# Using Rails and ActiveSupport, how can I get the offset of a timezone taking into account Dayling Time Saving?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timezone, activesupport, timezone-offset

I have a string that represents a date time. For example:

"2013-10-29T08:30:00"

that does not have time zone information, but I know that it represents a time in specific time zone, e.g. "Central Time (US & Canada)"

I want to create a correct `DateTime` object with correct time zone information, but I fail to do that, because I do not know whether I should use "-06:00" or "-05:00" as an offset (due to DST).

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No worries about DST at all :) ActiveSupport will take care of that for you.

```
Time.zone = "Central Time (US & Canada)"

t = Time.zone.parse "2013-10-29T08:30:00"
#=> Tue, 29 Oct 2013 08:30:00 CDT -05:00

t.dst?
#=> true
```

Ref about time zone setting and `dst?` http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone.html

Update: The above block is for showing purpose. In app, you can set time zone at `config/application.rb`

```
config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'
```

This will set default `Time.zone` so you no longer need the first line of above code.

Comment: ActiveRecord should also store everything in the DB as UTC, so converting in/out of different time zones *should* also be trivial, so long as you know which timezones you're converting between.

Comment: @jefflunt, thanks for the hint, I've updated answer. Also I guess OP's time record is not from ActiveRecord which always have UTC attached.

Comment: @BillyChan Thanks for answer. So, if I do not want to change the global time zone (`Time.zone= xxxx`), I suppose that I have to, first save it in a temporary variable (e.g. `temp = Time.zone`), then change it, then parse, and then revert back to the saved time zone. Is that correct?

Comment: @p.matsinopoulos, this seems not a conventional usage. If you set `temp = Time.zone` and assign timezone to `temp`, `temp` will be a string and calculation on time zone will still depend on previous timezone. So I doubt your method will work. The hack would be, I guess, work on Time.zone directly, after finish, revert to global one. However, if possible, I suggest you to convert all the time data into UTC to get a much better consistency and flexibility.

Comment: @BillyChan I think we are on the same page: 1) `temp = Time.zone` 2) `Time.zone = "Central Time (US & Canada)"` 3) `t = Time.zone.parse "2013-10-29T08:30:00"` 4) `Time.zone = temp` 5) `return t`

Comment: @p.matsinopoulos, yes, that should work and we meant same thing:)